# stripe subscription pay now and the first of each month

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm attempting to create subscriptions through the Stripe API.  I already create the products and items and now need to submit the subscription for the user, but I need to charge the customer for the full price now - no matter which day of the month it is - then charge at the beginning of each month - even if it starts tomorrow.

It looks like I could create a one-off item to charge for now then set up a subscription for the monthly billing cycle, but I'm wondering if I can do it all in one call with the subscription => create function.  I do not want to prorate the first month and I cannot see a way to tell it to charge the full price now and set up recurring on the first of each month following.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about the flow you're describing is to combine the [`backdate_start_date`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-backdate_start_date) and [`billing_cycle_anchor`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-billing_cycle_anchor) properties. The idea is that when creating the subscription you would set the `billing_cycle_anchor` to the first of the next month, and you would set the `backdate_start_date` to the first of the current month. For example, say you wanted to sign up a user for a $10.00 subscription that starts today (February 5th), but you want to bill them for the full $10.00 right away (even though they missed the first 5 days). Then, you want to bill them $10.00 again on March 1st, and the first of every month thereafter. When creating the subscription you would set:

- `billing_cycle_anchor`: 1614556800 (March 1st)
- `backdate_start_date`: 1612137600 (February 1st)

Which would result in a $10.00 invoice today, and a $10.00 invoice again on the first of March, and subsequent $10.00 invoices on the first of every month going forward.

Here's what this would look like in Node:

```
(async () => {
  const product = await stripe.products.create({ name: "t-shirt" });

  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    name: "Jenny Rosen",
    email: "jenny.rosen@gmail.com",
    payment_method: "pm_card_visa",
    invoice_settings: {
      default_payment_method: "pm_card_visa",
    },
  });

  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [
      {
        quantity: 1,
        price_data: {
          unit_amount: 1000,
          currency: "usd",
          recurring: {
            interval: "month",
          },
          product: product.id,
        },
      },
    ],
    backdate_start_date: 1612137600,
    billing_cycle_anchor: 1614556800,
    expand: ["latest_invoice"],
  });

  console.log(subscription);
})();
```

Comment: I literally just figured this out too but you already posted the answer I see.  haha, yeah, the `backdate_start_date` is what I needed.

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing, but the resulting invoice always has a few cents more than the fixed price. And they seem to be random, I have no idea where they are coming from.

Comment: I figured out what my problem was. I was working only with dates set to midnight on `backdate_start_date` and `billing_cycle_anchor `. Stripe somehow takes the current time when subscription is generated in combination with the `billing_cycle_anchor` to calculate prorations. Make sure you set the time part of the timestamp of both `backdate_start_date` and `billing_cycle_anchor` to the current time when you generate the subscription to get a nice round amount on the prorated invoice.